# Smart pointers with a resource manager that lets objects "borrow" resources

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I am somewhat new to the smart pointer world of C++ 11. I have been doing memory management manually and decided to dive into smart pointers. However, there is somewhat of a confusion though when it comes to `managers`

I define a manager as

> An object that owns and manages a set of objects. The objects are exclusively owned by the manager and it's the manager's responsibly to control their life cycle (ie. delete them). It dispenses the objects for use in other parts of the program, but does not give away ownership.

In other words, it lets other parts of the program borrow the resources it manages.

What I am a little bit confused about, is how to ensure ownership is preserved by the manager?

For instance, in a videogame, a 'Sprite' might request a 'Texture' from a texture manager. The sprite doesn't own the texture, it simply wants to use it. One way to do this, is to utilize a list of `unique_ptr`s. So I have:

```
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<SpriteTexture>> _spriteTextureList;
```

This however doesn't work, because I cannot establish a `weak_ptr` to a `unique_ptr`. On the other hand, I can create a list of shared_pointers

```
   std::list<std::shared_ptr<SpriteTexture>> _spriteTextureList;
```

This will allow me to dispense `weak_ptr` to other parts of the program. However, the issue is that a shared_pointer can be duplicated, breaking ownership apart to multiple pointers. This of course can be controlled if I never pass back a shared pointer, but doing this seems to be counter-intuitive for what a `shared_ptr` is meant to represent.

The third alternative would be to simply dispense `shared_ptr`. However, this is not useful because then the manager doesn't technically own the objects. If the manager removes a `Texture` out of it's list and something else has a `shared_ptr` to the `Texture`, then the texture wont be deleted.

In the ideal situation this should be just fine, because there should be no existing pointers to the `Texture` before the manager deletes it, but I can see this becoming a debugging hassle.

I definitely have a weak understanding of smart pointers. Maybe I am miss understanding how smart pointers are supposed to be implemented?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems to me that `std::shared_ptr` is just what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "it simply wants to use it", then `SpriteTexture*` is just fine. Normal pointers are fine, as long as they don't have ownership semantics associated with them.

Just use your first solution (`std::unique_ptr`) and dispense normal pointers obtained with `get()`.

You just have to make sure there are no other parts of the code using such a pointer when the manager decides to get rid of the associated object, but that's the opposite problem to the one in your question. (You sort of implied this wouldn't be a problem in your application.)

---

A side note: I can't think of a reason to use a `std::list` to hold those smart pointers. I think `std::vector` should be your first choice, unless you have a specific reason not to use it here.

Comment: I see what you are saying. My questions is: why is that better than just holding raw pointers in a std::list? It seems to me like std::unique_ptr is not different from just using normal pointers, other than the automatic deletion of the resource. But since the resource is being tightly controlled by the manager, the difference is calling delete on the object once it's removed from the std::list. I feel like I am missing the philosophy of why unique pointer is a useful tool. Maybe I am wedging smart pointers into somewhere where they don't belong?

Comment: @SergueiFedorov No, I don't think you're missing any philosophical aspects of `std::unique_ptr` here. That's exactly what it is: a way to ensure *only one* part of the code is responsible for cleaning up a resource. You can do things manually, of course, but you'll be opening up the code to all the risks that come with that. What if you miss something when doing maintenance on this piece of code at a later date? What if you forget to manually call delete in case an exception is thrown at some point in the process? These are just a couple of examples, of course there are more.

Comment: @bogden I guess I am coming from the idea that not only should smart pointers clean up resources, but they should communicate ownership as well. I am curious how you would communicate that a pointer is owned, if I simply return the raw pointer. Imagine it like this: Someone else comes a long to maintain my code. They see a raw pointer to `Texture` in my `Sprite` class. To them it might not be clear who owns the resource and they might assume the `Sprite` does. The reason I brought up `weak_ptr` is that it make it clear to the observer that this is not an owned resource. Does this make sense?

Comment: @SergueiFedorov Yes, it does make sense, and no, I wouldn't think like that :-). That's the thing: in modern C++ code, seeing a naked pointer should *never* imply ownership. (Of course it's essential to document these things, but that goes for pretty much everything important.) It's the other way around: if you want to communicate to client code that *it* is the owner, *then* return a `unique_ptr` to the resource, and don't hold any owning pointers to it in the manager.

Comment: If you have a resource for which pointers are passed around in your application code, with no central ownership, and you want it destroyed when it just happens that every part of the code has finished using it, then use `shared_ptr`. And, if you have parts of the code that just want to observe that pointer, and not have a say in its lifetime, then `weak_ptr` makes sense for those parts, since from their point of view destruction can happen at any time and they need to check if the pointer is still valid.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand what you are saying. I am thinking of it the other way around. To communicate explicit ownership, an object should be utilizing std::unique_ptr for the resource. Let's say in a different game engine, the `Sprite` owns its `Texture`. It would be using a std::unique_ptr. In my case, a naked pointer is more likely to communicate that the `Texture` is a borrowed resource.

Comment: @SergueiFedorov That's exactly how I think about it. Just one more thing, to be clear: you said "It would be using a std::unique_ptr" - "using", as in holding that `unique_ptr` somewhere in the `Sprite` implementation, and not giving it away. You cannot make copies of `unique_ptr`s, you can only `std::move` them, so if you give a `unique_ptr` away, you're automatically relinguishing ownership. It's basically the same thing that I said before, but now `Sprite` is the 'manager'.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant. The `Sprite` has sole ownership of the `Texture`. I'll try to be explicit next time! Thanks for clearing things up for me!